# How to cache method results in .Net

Tags: .net, caching, methods

Using webmethods, caching the results is pretty straight forward using "CacheDuration" attribute. Is there a similar "easy" way to cache non-webmethod outputs (or static methods) based on the parameters?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to implement a cache is to use a Dictionary or similar data structure within your class to hold results in memory for successive calls.

```
public class CachedDatastore
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void FindById(string id)
    {
        if (!cache.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            var data = GetDataFromDatabase(id);
            cache[id] = data;
        }

        return cache[id];
    }
}
```

This is just a basic example if you want to try to implement something on your own.  It does not support cache "eviction" or re-loading data at any time.  If you need more advanced features, I'd recommend looking around in the .NET framework for cache classes or other 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Hello, Andy. Thanks for the reply, but I was looking for a more easier way to implement across many different methods without having to do them individually. 

For example, annotating a static method of some attribute which enables caching of that method, similar to WebMethod's "CacheDuration". 

Is there another easy way that I am missing? If not, is there an example of attribute programming that can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This question looks similar to: [Is there anyway to cache function/method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929540/is-there-anyway-to-cache-function-method-in-c-sharp)

The right term for what you want is [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Wikipedia gives more details on this subjects. Unfortunately there is no reference to a C# library supporting it. There are various ways to implement it yourself. But since I am not experienced in C# I can not give any more detail. Some techniques that could be used: AOP, Annotations, Proxies.