# How to Log every function call in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, trace, error-logging

Currently, Our Asp.Net web application is having 600+ pages. We have already implemented Microsoft Enterprise Library for Logging. But, problem is we have lot of navigation's in the application. When clients posted some issues, We are unable to find where code is failing.

So, Please suggest us some open source third party tool to Log every function call through out the application with less code changes in pages. Like, log every function from Global.asax or Some class in AppCode.

We have already using Log4net for some other purpose in the web application.

My idea is to log every function call without going to 600+ pages and make code changes. Is that possible?

Comment: are you using MVC pattern?

Comment: No..3-Tier Architecture.

Comment: No i mean are u using ASP.NET MVC with filters ?

Comment: No. we are not using that

Comment: did u check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: @Praveen You could possibly do it by introducing some aspect oriented programming... Have a look at https://www.postsharp.net/aspects

Comment: Yes. I have checked this. But this will trace only asp.net Events I think. But we need to trace every c# function call too.

Comment: @PaulZahra I have seen postsharp. But it is not open source. Is there any open source tool like Postsharp.

Comment: Use ELMAH http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx

Comment: @Praveen There is a free version of PostSharp, also the diagnostic toolkit is only £29.. Not sure about .Net only, however have you had a look at their diagnostics toolkit? It's multi framework compatible, and reportedly only takes minutes to setup?!?!?! https://www.postsharp.net/diagnostics/net-logging

Comment: @Praveen This may interest you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115909/any-free-alternative-to-postsharp especially ninject interception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 4 intercept all incoming requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726848/asp-net-mvc-4-intercept-all-incoming-requests)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a new logging tool. I would recommend using [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/). All you have to do is to place tiny chunk of code in your `global.asax` file and that's it. `ELMAH` will log any errors in your application. It will tell the file name, function and exact line number where the error occurred. It also gives you a stack trace of all functions called prior. It's very powerful, simple to work with, and free.